# What is the APIs differences in Solr and Aws CloudSearch?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr, solrcloud

I'm looking into the migration of Solr to AWS CloudSearch before start investigate myself, thought of asking a question to the community.

My current application is in **ASP.NET MVC C#** and using the **SolrNet.dll** for Solr Service.

If anybody did the migration then please share your experiences, Is there any changes in the return JSON results, or query parameters or APIs.

Appreciate your helps on this.

Comment: I would definitely **not** migrate from Solr to CloudSearch.  It's built on top of a grossly outdated version of Solr, and from my interactions with AWS support and an AWS solution architect, it's very clear that they have no immediate plans to upgrade CloudSearch.  The last feature update to CloudSearch was in March of 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon cloudsearch is based on solr, so conceptually they work same way, but amazon has written its own wrapper on top of solr api.

- Amazon cloud search has two endpoints, one for search and other for
  indexing documents.
- Amazon cloudsearch has four different query parsers, if you place
  queries using  Lucence as query parser, query syntax and
  functionality is same.
- The only difference I observed functionally is cloudsearch doesn't
  support hierarchy in fields data, it only provides with text and
  literal datatypes and their arrays for multiple values.